# Deadlock on banker's algorithm

Tags: operating-system, bankers-algorithm

When preforming the banker's algorithm, what happens when there is a deadlock? Will it pick the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The banker's algorithm is used to avoid deadlocks, not to handle them. If a system is working under this algorithm you won't have any dead lock. If a request of resources by a process could take the system to a dead lock the process has to wait until more resources are avaible.